# Display Complex key-value pair in AG-Grid

Tags: html, angular, sorting, frontend, ag-grid

I have a map that I am sending to Angular via API and I would like to display it in ag-grid.
The map has key as date and value as a list of objects
This is how the map looks like:

`{ 2019-12-23 00:00:00.0: Array(3),2019-05-24 00:00:00.0: Array(1)}`

This is how the object looks like
`{"id":5, "amt":10,"status":new}`

So I want the display the same in ag-grid such that I can sort it on the basis of the amt field.
So something like:

(Assume from above map obj1,obj2,obj3 are in the first array i.e. having key as 2019-12-23 00:00:00.0 and obj4 having key as 2019-05-24 00:00:00.0 and assume obj1.amt > obj4.amt > obj2.amt > obj3.amt).

```
2019-12-23 00:00:00.0 | obj1.id| obj1.amt |obj1.status
2019-05-24 00:00:00.0 | obj4.id| obj4.amt |obj4.status
2019-12-23 00:00:00.0 | obj2.id| obj2.amt |obj2.status
2019-12-23 00:00:00.0 | obj3.id| obj3.amt |obj3.status
```

How can I achieve this? Any code snippet would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implementation could be different based on time property

Do you need time in the table?

**if - NO** - solution will be much easier

```js
const entireObject = {
[new Date(1000).toISOString()]: [ {"id":5, "amt":10,"status":'new'},  {"id":6, "amt":10,"status":'new'}],
[new Date(2000).toISOString()]: [ {"id":7, "amt":10,"status":'new'},  {"id":8, "amt":10,"status":'new'}]
}
const outputData = Object.values(entireObject).flat();
console.log(outputData)
```

**if - YES**

```js
const entireObject = {
[new Date(1000).toISOString()]: [ {"id":5, "amt":10,"status":'new'},  {"id":6, "amt":10,"status":'new'}],
[new Date(2000).toISOString()]: [ {"id":7, "amt":10,"status":'new'},  {"id":8, "amt":10,"status":'new'}]
}
const outputData = Object.entries(entireObject).map(([time, arr]) => arr.map( i => ({...i, time}))).flat();
console.log(outputData);
```

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/97AVLXG8GeSzc7wo

example

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks this works for me.
Since I am getting time from API itself so doing this  
  Object.values(entireObject).flat();   should work right?